# Full finite abelian subcategories of $A\text{-mod}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-categories, algebras

I'm only ever thinking about finite-dimensional $k$-algebras instead of general rings.
Let $A$ be such an algebra.
My question is:

- Are full finite abelian subcategories of $A\text{-mod}$ precisely the categories of modules over quotients $A/I$ for ideals $I\leq A$?

I think I can show: $I\leq A$ then $A/I\text{-mod} \subset A\text{-mod}$ is full (of course it's finite abelian).

But if $S \subset A\text{-mod}$, then I don't see why $\operatorname{End}_S(P) \cong A/I$, for a progenerator $P \in S$ and some ideal $I\leq A$.
My idea is that the minimal projective generator of $S$ is a quotient of the minimal projective generator of $A\text{-mod}$, namely the quotient by the sum of projective covers of simples in $A\text{-mod}$ that are not in $S$.
How to take it from there?

Comment: What does "finite" mean here?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Definition 1.8.6 in EGNO, basically an abelian category with adjectives st it is equivalent to fd modules over the fd algebra $\operatorname{Hom}(P,P)$ for a projective generator $P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $M$ be any finitely generated $A$-module with $\operatorname{End}_A(M)=k$. Then the category of finite direct sums of copies of $M$ is a full finite abelian subcategory of  $A\text{-mod}$ (it is equivalent to $k\text{-mod}$), but unless $M$ is simple, it won't be of the form $(A/I)\text{-mod}$, as it won't be closed under taking quotients and submodules.

Comment: Oh huh, right, an inclusion can be exact without its image being closed under quotients and subobjects. Funny stuff.

Comment: I am clearly confused about basics: Some people will call objects in $k$-linear abelian categories _(absolutely) simple_ if their endomorphisms are $k$. How does that definition agree with "unless $M$ is simple"?

Comment: @JoMo An object can have endomorphism ring $k$ without being simple. E.g., let $A$ be the algebra of upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrices, and $M$ the left ideal consisting of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard: I see, thank you very much!